# How do I remove the qvo6 homepage?

Tags: browser, virus-removal, malware-removal

Every time I open my browsers, be it Firefox, Chrome, Dragon, or [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29), the qvo6.com page loads. The homepages for these browsers are set to blank. Yet this problem persists.

http://qvo6.com/uninstall.html doesn't seem to work at all!

I've tried TrendMicro's HijackThis, and it still doesn't seem to help.

Any means to remove this annoying thing? I don't remember what caused this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bleepingcomputer.com always have fantastic guides on how to remove nasty programs from computers.

Here is their guide regarding qv06: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-qvo6.com-browser-hijacker

Give this a go, start to finish.